# How to change value of excel cell +1 or -1 using AppleScript

Tags: excel, shell, automation, applescript

I am trying to write a script where a combination of the text returned and button returned results in a change made to a specific cell in an open excel sheet. Basically add 1 or subtract 1 from the current value of the cell specified. The only thing that works right now using the code below is when the user clicks the
-cancel- button I get the dialog "No change was made." this is as expected.

I don't get any error when I enter the text "12502525981" and click the add button. simply nothing happens.

Also I think I'm not telling excel +1 the way that it expects me to.

many thanks

[image: dialog picture]
[image]

```
try
set upcItem1 to "12502525981"
set upcItem2 to "12502600695"
set upcItem3 to "12502612346"

set the_Response to {text returned, button returned} of (display dialog "Enter the UPC of the item below..." buttons {"Add +1 ", "-Cancel-", "Remove -1"} default answer "")
item 1 of the_Response -- the text
item 2 of the_Response -- the button pressed

if item 2 of the_Response is equal to "Add +1" & item 1 of the_Response contains upcItem1 then
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        set value of cell "C2" to current value +1
    end tell

else if item 2 of the_Response is equal to "Remove -1" & item 1 of the_Response contains upcItem1 then
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        set value of cell "C2" to current value -1
    end tell

else if item 2 of the_Response is equal to "-Cancel-" then
    display notification "No change was made."
end if
on error
display notification "There was a problem with the UPC entered, try again or check the cell that it relates to."
end try
```

Comment: Why not use VBA built in to Excel?

Comment: Macros is not allowed in my organization. So I have to resort to other methods

Answer (score 0):

```
    set x to display dialog "Enter the UPC of the item below..." default answer "" buttons {"Add +1", "-Cancel-", "Remove -1"} default button 2
set {runButton, textButton} to {button returned of x, text returned of x}

if runButton is "Add +1" then
    try
        set myValue to (textButton + 1)
    on error
        display dialog "There was a problem with the UPC entered, try again or check the cell that it relates to."
        return
    end try

else if runButton is "Remove -1" then
    try
        set myValue to (textButton - 1)
    on error
        display dialog "There was a problem with the UPC entered, try again or check the cell that it relates to."
        return
    end try

else if runButton is "-Cancel-" then
    display dialog "No change was made."
    return
end if

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell active sheet
        set value of cell "C2" to myValue
    end tell
end tell

display dialog "Done"
```

Comment: so with this it looks like your trying to add 1 to the UPC barcode that the user is inputing. Im trying to add 1 to the quantity which is located in cell C2. (Is my understanding correct?)